# Transform Equirectangular Projection to Azimuthal Projection

Tags: python, projection, panoramas, azimuth

I am trying to transform an [equirectangular projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equirectangular_projection) to an [azimuthal projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Azimuthal_equidistant_projection) with python. I have found [py360convert](https://github.com/sunset1995/py360convert), which allows convert from equirectangular to cubemap, from which it should be easier to obtain an azimuthal projection.

Does someone know a python solution to get the Azimuthal projection from an Equirectangular o from an cubemap?

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: I reformulate the question